# Inputs within double `while` loop are not happening

Tags: shell, ksh

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  i=0;
  rm -rf b.txt
  while [[ $i -lt $line ]]
  do
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    echo "$i " >> b.txt
  done
  a=`cat b.txt`
  for i in $a;
  do
    echo "Hari $i \c"
    read input
  done
done < 5.txt
```

Say *5.txt* has the value:

```
2
3
```

This script needs to place the cursor inside the `for` loop, but the script is continuously executing and ending.  Can you please help me over this?

Comment: could you describe what the script should do?

Comment: The Script should print the first line from the file 5.txt then it should take input from user for 2 times(since the first line in 5.txt has the value 2). Then it should print the next line then it should take input from the user for 3 times(since the second line of the file 5.txt has a value 3). It should continue even when the file contains many lines

Comment: When `2 3`  are on the same linte, they will be assigned to `$line` together.

Comment: When you want to read from stdin, the while loop needs to read from another fd. Try `while IFS= read -r line<&3; do ... done 3< 5.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *5.txt* consists of:

```
2
3
```

The script outputs:

```
2
Hari 1 \c
Hari 2 \c
```

...and quits.

The script won't prompt for input after outputting `Hari 1 \c` because **all** the input is coming from *5.txt*.  On the **first** pass *$input* would be set to *3*, (the 2nd line of *5.txt*).  On the **second** pass, the input would be an EOF, in which case `read` gives up, much like how this outputs *nothing*:

```
read -p "Enter a number" n < /dev/null
```

This would work:

```
for i in `cat 5.txt` ; do \
    echo $i ; for f in `seq $i` ; do read -p "Hari $f \c: " input ; done ; \
done
```

Note also that `$input` is never used for anything.